# Numbers table vs recursive CTE to generate a range of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is using a numbers table so much faster than using a recursive CTE to generate them on the fly?

On my machine, given a table `numbers` with a single column `n` (primary key) containing the numbers from 1 to 100000, the following query:

```
select n from numbers;
```

Takes around 400 ms to finish.

Using a recursive CTE to generate the numbers 1 to 100000:

```
with u as (
    select 1 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from u
    where n < 100000
)
select n
from u
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

Takes about 900ms to finish, both on SQL Server 2019.

My question is, why is the second option so much slower than the first one? Isn't the first one fetching results from disk, and should therefore be slower?

Otherwise, is there any way to make the CTE run faster? Because it seems to me it's a more elegant solution than storing a list of numbers in a database.

Comment: Wouldn't they both be fetching from disk then since they reference the same table?

Comment: Simple, the SQL Server engine is optimised for set based operations, not recursive ones.

Comment: @shawnt00 edited the second example to `u` instead of `numbers` to avoid confusion. I tried it and it still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Run both your queries with `set statistics io, time on` and you'll see the reasons; the recursive CTE will be burning CPU, reading from the table will be much faster, especially on subsequent runs when the data pages will be cached in ram; ymmv.

Comment: _it's a more elegant solution than storing a list of numbers in a database_ How many times will you or anyone else need such a table? In general, many times because it has so many uses. So why do you consider this "inelegant"? And how exactly do you measure "elegance"? But I leave you with the discussion of [fastest number series generator](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) if you really want to know.

Comment: Also, we’re still talking about less than a second here, and is your plan really to time how fast it takes to generate _and render_ 100,000 rows in isolation? Why don’t you measure what you actually plan to do with this range of numbers instead of how long it takes SSMS to render the entire set?

Comment: I always wonder why people object to creating a table - the storage requirement pays for itself almost immediately because if the table is read frequently enough (and it should be!) it’s always in memory. Memory is pretty fast. Also see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/1186).

Comment: @AaronBertrand from a practical standpoint I agree. It's just that storing something that can be generated isn't minimalistic and sounds like a dirty hack.

Comment: Not everything has to be minimalistic, in fact I’d argue that if storing it is more efficient than generating it every time, you’ve got it backwards.

Comment: Storing a few hundred 8k pages once in a utility database for reuse by any number of queries over multiple databases on the server and can be read in a few milliseconds with negligible CPU versus repeating the same expensive CPU cycles to generate the same list on every invocation, especially when being charged for CPU in the cloud.... I know what I'd consider the minimal approach!

Comment: More of my own commentary on the value of a numbers table: [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/) | [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4177/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't the first one fetching results from disk, and should therefore
> be slower?

100,000 integers will fit on around 161 data pages (assuming no compression is in use) - each row will be 11 bytes and consume 2 bytes in the slot array.

When you ran your tests it is possible that the data was in cache already. Even if none was in cache it is very possible that nearly all of the pages were already read into cache by the read ahead mechanism before they were needed so IO waits are minimal and it is again just a CPU bound operation. (You can use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to see how many physical reads and read ahead reads were actually required)

Reading rows from a data page in cache is something that SQL Server is, of course, good at. From an execution plan point of view there is no complexity at all. The correct rows can be returned from an index seek operator (ideally or scan operator otherwise) and output straight to the client with no additional operators needed.

The recursive CTE functionality is a generic method that always uses fundamentally the same execution plan. Row(s) from the anchor part are added to an stack spool and then popped (removed) from the spool to feed into a nested loops operator which calculates the recursive part on its inner sub-tree and passes values up the execution plan tree to be added to the stack spool (for further recursion) and returned to the client.

All these execution plan operations take time. I tried for numbers up to `10,000,000` on my local machine. The overall query duration was 2m 6s (of which 38 seconds was spent on exactly 9,999,999 `PAGELATCH_SH` waits in `tempdb` for the spool)

The reason for these latch waits is described in the [lazy latches section](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-plan/optimizing-update-queries) here. The table spool operator holds the latch on the page but then when the index spool operator tries to insert the row for the next number (in the same underlying spool) it is blocked by the other operator. So has to enter a wait state that releases the latch and unblocks itself. (specifically it is under `IndexDataSetSession::LocatePageForInsert` which presumably explains why it is waiting in `SH` mode rather than `EX`). There are relatively so many of them in this case because every number being returned is at a different recursion level, so all the inserts only do one row before the table spool gets called again to replay that row.

You can see the "per operator" timings below. The table spool operator (node 6) spends an appreciable time mainly as it deletes the row from the spool every time it emits one. Node 0 is the operator that inserts rows to the spool. Essentially every number returned goes through this wait/insert/delete cycle (though the single initial row inserted to the spool by the anchor statement can do so without waiting)

[image]

[image]

Certainly it would be possible to provide a function like the Postgres [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) one that is entirely CPU based and just dedicated to the task of supplying incrementing values and [indeed this was done in SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

On previous versions the "state of the art" approach to produce numbers without a numbers table was probably the one mentioned first in [this page](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/05/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-5).

Comment: This is very useful!. I am interested to know about the program you have used that breaks it down by function time

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph this is from attaching the Visual Studio debugger to my local SQL Server (having configured VS to use the Microsoft Public symbol server) then using the CPU profiling option whilst the query is running. It is also possible to use Windows Performance Recorder for this too

Comment: Is generate_series usually the go to option when a range of numbers is needed for Postgres users?

Comment: I Don't know. @Zakaria. I work pretty much exclusively with SQL Server so don't know if there are cases where that wouldn't be the best option

Comment: Erland Sommarskog opened a "Connect" item on that very subject almost 12 years ago.  The responses from MS seemed to indicate that they had no clue what such a thing would be used for even though a few of us gave actual examples.  The item stayed open through all the different platforms that the original "connect" went through to ultimately land in GIT and still not even a suggestion that they do such a thing.  If they ever do, one can only hope they don't mess it up like they did with the original STRING_SPLIT() or the performance issue with FORMAT.

Comment: @JeffModen - yeah would hope that if it is implemented they think about things like giving it an accurate cardinality estimate for the range requested (at least if using literals) as it should know exactly how many rows will be required. And hopefully uniqueness and ordered properties will be set the same as if it was actually getting the values from a unique index

Comment: `GENERATE_SERIES` is being implemented in SQL Server 2022. For details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 6):

The recursive CTE is a CPU expensive operation because SQL Server "loops" over reach row. A materialized numbers table or set-based CTE will perform much faster. Note the CPU and elapsed times reported with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` on my workstation (YMMV).

Numbers table:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.numbers;

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 231 ms.
```

Recursive CTE:

```
with u as (
    select 1 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from u
    where n < 100000
)
select n
from u
option(maxrecursion 0);

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 375 ms,  elapsed time = 529 ms.
```

Set-based CTE:

```
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t100k AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS n FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
SELECT n
FROM t100k;

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 223 ms.
```

An advantage of the numbers table is that the unique index can be leveraged to optimize certain queries, although not applicable here.

Comment: What makes you say it's CPU expensive as opposed to IO? I'm under the impression it requires inserting and reading rows from a worktable, which even given the removal of eager writes (and therefore only writing to memory), is still going to be the major cause of the slowdown

Comment: @Charlieface, by CPU expensive, I was referring to all compute costs (i.e. other physical IO) Martin detailed in his answer, including logical IO. The original question called out disk IO, which I interpreted to mean physical IO from storage.

Answer (score -2):

When you declare a column as primary key, SQL Server creates a clustered index so it means if you query that table with the primary key SQL Server query optimizer exactly knows where that column is. In other words this query is as efficient as it could be, with minimum CPU time and logical reads.
To see a detailed view of the difference between these two approaches, enable the execution plan WITH `Ctrl+m` run  the query and compare two execution plans.

Comment: "When you declare a column as primary key, SQL Server creates a clustered index" by default yes, but only if you don't change it. This doesn't explain why a recursive CTE is slower though.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by " but only if you don't change it." 
This explains why selecting from a table and filtering by a column that has a index on has the least amount of io and CPU time. comparing to cte which consumes much more CPU poswer.

Comment: What I meant was that you don't have to create your primary key as a clustered index... its optional.