# Can I use an OPTION clause inside a function in T-SQL (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, sql-function

I want to write a function like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TestFunction()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
WITH NumberList AS (
    SELECT  1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Number + 1
    FROM    NumberList
    WHERE   Number < 1000
)
SELECT  Number
FROM    NumberList
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

However, when running this query, SQL Server returns the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestFunction, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.
```

If I remove the row `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` from the function it works:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TestFunction()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
WITH NumberList AS (
    SELECT  1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Number + 1
    FROM    NumberList
    WHERE   Number < 1000
)
SELECT  Number
FROM    NumberList
```

But when executing this function:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    TestFunction()
```

Then it returns the following error:

```sql
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

Is it possible to add the clause `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` inside the function? I think it would be convenient for the user of the function not having to remember to add the option clause when executing the function.

Comment: add the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to your final query, not the view. `SELECT * FROM TestFunction() OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: That's not a great way to generate a numbers table BTW. You have an XY problem

Comment: A tally would be a much better way; it's faster and doesn't require recursion. If you're on 2022+ then use `GENERATE_SERIES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better approach to generate numbers from 1 to 1000 will be using master..spt_values as below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TestFunction()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
  
WITH NumberList AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Number
  FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT Number
FROM NumberList
WHERE Number <= 1000;
```

```
select * from  TestFunction()
```

```
+------------------------------------+
|               Number               |
+------------------------------------+
| 1                                  |
| 2                                  |
| 3                                  |
| ... --4 to 995 omitted for brevity |
| 996                                |
| 997                                |
| 998                                |
| 1000                               |
+------------------------------------+
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BqQqvx31)

Comment: We really don't need that massive markdown table...

Comment: My `master..spt_values` table contains 2552 rows, so for my case it's a great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just beware that selecting from master..spt_values is slow in comparison to the cross-join values table constructor method.

Comment: @DanielJonsson - You can just do `SELECT number FROM master..spt_values where type = N'P' and number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000` because it already has those numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Using recursion to generate a number series has considerable overhead and is probably one of the slowest possible ways to do it.

The absolute fastest way, prior to SQL Server 2022, to generate a number series would be to use a cross join using a derived table of values. This is faster than even select integers from a physical table, also a common option.

The following will give you exactly 1000 rows. If you wanted fewer rows you could use `top` when you select from it, or pass in a parameter to use for `top` when you invoke it.

```
create function dbo.GenerateSeries()
returns table
as return
with 
    t1(n) as (select n from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))n(n)), 
    t2(n) as (select 0 from t1 x cross join t1 y),
    t3(n) as (select 0 from t2 x cross join t1 y), 
    t(n) as (select Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) from t3)
select n
from t;
```

Comment: Some details on the "considerable overhead" https://stackoverflow.com/a/70500904